# Norm of integral operator from $(C[0,1], \|\|_1)$ to $(C[0,1], \|\|_2).$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $\|\|_1$ be sup-norm and $\|f\|_2=(\int_0^1|f(t)|^2dt)^{\frac{1}{2}}$. Define linear operator $T$ from  $(C[0,1], \|\|_1)$ to $(C[0,1], \|\|_2)$ as $$T(f)(t)=\int_0^tf(s)ds$$  Then norm of $T$ is

$1.$ $1$.

$2.$ $\frac{1}{2}.$

$3.$ $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}.$

$4.$ none .

I am trying it like this

$$\|T(f)(t)\|=(\int_0^1|\int_0^tf(s)ds|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\leq (\int_0^1\int_0^t\|f\|^2_1ds)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\|f\|_1(\int_0^1tdt )^{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\|f\|_1$$ please help me to solve this problem . Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\|f\|_1 \leq 1$. By C-S inequality we have $|Tf(t)| \leq  t$. Hence, $\|Tf\|_2\leq \frac1  {\sqrt 3}$. This value is attained when $f\equiv 1$ so $\|T\|=\frac 1 {\sqrt3 }$.

Note that $|\int_0^{t} f(s)ds| \leq \sqrt {\int_0^{t} 1^{2}ds} {\sqrt {\int_0^{t} f^{2}(s)ds}}\leq t$